# How to upload large excel contaning 11 million records into datatable C# windows application?

Tags: c#-4.0

```
 private void Import_To_Grid(string FilePath, string Extension, string isHDR)
{
    string conStr="";
    switch (Extension)
    {
        case ".xls":
            conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"]
                     .ConnectionString;
            break;
        case ".xlsx":
            conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"]
                      .ConnectionString;
            break;
    }
    conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR);
    OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
    OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;


    connExcel.Open();
    DataTable dtExcelSchema;
    dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    connExcel.Close();

    //Read Data from First Sheet
    connExcel.Open();
    cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
    oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
    oda.Fill(dt);
    connExcel.Close();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is - you don't.  Eleven million rows?  You need to process these row-by-row with an OldDbDataReader, and not try jamming them all in RAM at once with a DataTable.